# ERROR: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, arrays, split

This is my code:

```
line = open('save_file.txt')

s = {}
(s['nome'], s['race'], s['classes'], s['FOR'], s['INT'], s['DES']) = line.split(";")

print("Nome: " + s['nome'])
print("Raça: " + s['race'])
```

I'm trying to print the things that are in the `save_file`, but when I start the program the error of the title appears. Someone can help?
Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` returns file object, not line. You need something like

```
f = open('save_file.txt')
for line in f:
   #do stuff
```